# How do I stream sound from an Android device to a Java Server?

Tags: java, android, audio, stream

I want to stream audio to a Java server I'll create myself. At the moment I'm stuck since i don't know how to achieve this. Are there any good tutorials on this topic or something similar?

Is streaming much more advanced than simple recording and sending the audio when its done?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where you want to keep archive ? on the server side?

Comment: Yes, server side. I will run the server om my local machine and pass the stream to other clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually keeps only url to file.

You can try create blob(byte objects) in your database and then send those object to the clients.

Comment: Im sorry i made it sound more complicated than it is, i dont intend to save the sound afterwards, just play it on the other end. Which means i dont use a database, its the streaming thats bothering me